# Why is the GranthedAuthorities in UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken empty?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, authentication, spring-security

I am stuck with this Java Spring boot problem.
I have filled the **autorities:** *this.getAuthorities(user)* in the return statement of the **loadUserByUsername** method.
but when I print out the Authentication object it says that the Granted Authorities is empty:

**UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=mark, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=null, Granted Authorities=[]]**

Does anyone have any idea?

Extra Info:
*User.getRole() == "Role_Default"*

```
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
        if (user == null) throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), this.getAuthorities(user));
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "authenticated")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_DEFAULT')")
    public User getAuthenticatedUser() {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        System.out.println(auth);
        User user = this.getUserByUsername(auth.getPrincipal().toString());
        return user;
    }

    private Collection<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(User user) {
        Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(user.getRole()));
        return authorities;
    }
```

Comment: if your code is reaching this line `System.out.println(auth);` that means user has this authority at least if not more.

Comment: Hey Ekansh, it seems like all users with different roles can access it. So the PreAuthorize is not working

Comment: can you put a breakpoint at the return line in getAuthorities method, and check what does include authorities list?

Comment: Hey Velat, i used the debugger and my loadedUser object has the granted Authorities: **org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User [Username=mark, Password=[PROTECTED], Enabled=true, AccountNonExpired=true, credentialsNonExpired=true, AccountNonLocked=true, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_DEFAULT]]**, but in the Authentication object the Granted Authorities is empty

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this problem as well. I have a custom UserCredentials implementing `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails` with getAuthorities() implementation returning values - but noting worked Authorities array was empty:

```
o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor:317 - Re-authenticated UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=dto.UserCredentials@585027b7, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=null, **Granted Authorities=[]**] before authorizing
```

The problem was that my implementation of AuthenticationProvider was wrong, it returned :

```
new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userCredentials, authentication, Collections.emptyList());
```

Instead of the correct:

```
new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userCredentials, authentication, **userCredentials.getAuthorities()**);
```